# Socket multiple clients

Tags: java, client-server

Suppose I have 4 clients having port num 1,2,3,4 respectively and one server.

I want to make a connection between server and client and then send clients name and ipaddress to server and simple read that string on server.
In server side socket programming I have used a for loop to access respective clients on port 1,2,3,4.

Now my question is when the client on portnum 2 is not active, server should wait for 1 second and then move to next port num 3 but it is happening so server is stuck in that loop until it makes a connection to portnum 2.

I have used `setSoTimeout` function but still problem isn't resolved.

Kindly help me

Server Side code is

```
package server;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server implements Runnable {
   Socket csocket;
   Server(Socket csocket) {
      this.csocket = csocket;
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) 
   throws Exception {
       for (int i=1; i<=4; i++) {
           ServerSocket ssock = new ServerSocket(i);
           System.out.println("Listening");
      //while (true) {
           Socket sock = ssock.accept();
           System.out.println("Connected");
           new Thread(new Server(sock)).start();
       }
   }

   public void run() {
      try {
           DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(csocket.getInputStream());
           String str=dis.readUTF();
           System.out.print(str);

           dis.close();
           csocket.close();
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println(e);
      }
   }
}
```

Client side code is

```
package client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Client
{
    Socket s;

    DataOutputStream dout;

    public Client() {
        while(true)
            try { 
              s=new Socket("192.168.1.101",1);
              dout= new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
              java.net.InetAddress j = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost();
              dout.writeUTF(j.getHostName()+"\t\t\t"+j.getHostAddress());
              //Userinfo();    
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             System.out.println(e);
         }
    }

//   public void Userinfo() throws UnknownHostException, IOException
//   {
//      
//       
//   }

   public static void main(String as[])
    {
        new Client(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you tidy up your formatting to make it more readable? You should be able to do this in your IDE with 1 operation.

Comment: The server can get the IP address of the client from the `Socket`

Comment: You appear to be listening on a port for each client (and you discard the ServerSocket). I suggest you use the same port for all clients, and keep the ServerSocket until the program has finished.

Comment: Why do you have `while(true)` in Client ? Do you want to keep sending host name and host address to Server?

Comment: Servers don't connect to clients. Clients connect to servers. You're thinking about this completely back to front.